# Modx revo + quip, добавить captcha

Tags: modx, captcha

Добрый вечер, друзья. Проблема у меня в том, что не могу понять, как подключить капчу в quip, но не reCaptcha, а какую-нибудь аналогичную(по проще типа введите 3х значное чилсло на картинке). Не могу догнать где, что в коде править. 
Укажите мне путь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навалял решение. Костыльное решение, но рабочее.core/components/quip/controllers/web/ThreadReply.php

1. В качестве капчи использовал
   [kcaptcha](http://captcha.ru/kcaptcha/), убрал шум, и оставил
   только цифры, все настраивается
   через конфигурационный файл
   kcaptcha_config.php
2. Закинул капчу по адресу assets/components/kcaptcha/
3. В файле index.php добавил поддержку API Modx для доступа к сессиям modx. Вот исправленное содержимое файла "**assets/components/kcaptcha/index.php**":

initialize('web');
    error_reporting (E_ALL);
    include('kcaptcha.php');
    session_start();
    $captcha = new KCAPTCHA();
    if($_REQUEST[session_name()]){
        $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] = $captcha->getKeyString();
    }

?>

4 Затем в файле **core/components/quip/controllers/web/ThreadReply.php** добавил следующий код в функцию handlePost()

5 Ну и кусок капчи в шаблоне формы комментария выглядит так:

```
<div class="quip-fld kcaptcha">
        <label><span>Введите цифры на картинке</span></label>
        <span class="quip-error">[[+error.kcaptcha]]</span>
        <img class="kcaptcha_image" src="[[++assets_url]]components/kcaptcha/?[[!returnSession? &param=`ses_name`]]=[[!returnSession? &param=`ses_id`]]">
        <input type="text" name="kcaptcha" id="quip-comment-kcaptcha-[[+idprefix]]" value="[[+kcaptcha]]" class="kcaptcha_field"/>
        <br />
    </div>
```

Может кому поможет, вот скрин :
[image]